# How to open applications in fullscreen via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, fullscreen

I just created a script to open my most-used apps, but I have two questions about it.

The code of the script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hi $(whoami)"
echo "Openning your default apps..."
open -a Mail
open -a Wunderlist
open -a Reminders
open -a Notes
open -a Pocket
open -a Safari
echo "Do you want social networks? [y|n]"
read social
if [[ $social == "y" ]]; then
    open -a Telegram
    open -a Safari http://web.whatsapp.com
    open -a TweetDeck
fi
echo "Do you want to listen some music? [y|n]"
read music
if [[ $music == "y" ]]; then
    open -a iTunes
fi
echo "Have a nice day $(whoami)! :D"
```

So here come the questions:

- How can I open those apps in fullscreen by default? iTunes have memory and open in fullscreen mode, but the others don't.
- How can I keep Terminal in foreground while the other apps are being open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I keep Terminal in foreground while the other apps are being open?

Use the `-g` or `--background` flag to `open`:

> ```
>  -g  Do not bring the application to the foreground.
> ```

for example:

`open -g -a Notes`

will open Notes.app in the background.

Unfortunately not all apps appear to respect this. For those apps you may need to hide them manually using AppleScript:

`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "FOO" to false'`

where `FOO` is the name of the app.

p.s. - instead of `$(whoami)` you can use `$LOGNAME`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer without using keystrokes (as I use [Rectangle](https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle) which uses the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> keystroke).

```bsh
oinfs() {
    for app in "${@}"
    do
        # get application name (applicationName) from case insensitive input
        # activate application (delay while app opens.  may need to be changed to delay 3)
        # set application to fullscreen
        osascript \
            -e "tell application \"System Events\"" \
                -e "set applicationName to name of my application \"${app}\"" \
            -e "end tell" \
            -e "tell application applicationName" \
                -e "activate" \
                -e "delay 1" \
                -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell process applicationName" \
                    -e "set value of attribute \"AXFullScreen\" of window 1 to true" \
                -e "end tell" \
            -e "end tell"
    done
}
```

To use this you can run

```bsh
oinfs Safari "Google Chrome" # or `oinfs Safari Google\ Chrome`
```

The first three lines of the script gets the application name from a case insensitive input, so you can also run

```bsh
oinfs safari google\ chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Fullscreen-question:
I guess there is other ways to do it but using AppleScript is one of them.

For Safari it would be something like this:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Safari"' -e "activate" -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}' -e "end tell" -e "end tell"
```

Just substitute the applications and the right keystroke in the line and use this instead of the 'open' command.

Comment: Where can I learn how to do AppleScript? Do you know any manual or website that explain the syntax?